# Websocket Handshaking Error in Python Django

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am getting issue with websocket connection as it is getting closed due to handshake error. The error message is as below:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/polData/ [127.0.0.1:59304]
Exception inside application: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 172, in __call__
    return await self.inner(self.scope, receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 160, in __call__
    send,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/asgiref/compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 159, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/polData/ [127.0.0.1:59304]\
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check your routing.py in app,

under **websocket_urlpatterns**, on **repath** you may have missed **.as_asgi()**

eg:-

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [

    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Comment: Hi @Shaheen - are you available for freelance consulting work in the Django/ channels space? We're based in Singapore and looking for Django developers based in India.

Answer (score 1):

In routing.py, "as_asgi()" is required for versions over python 3.6.

Here is how I solved the problem and kept allowing different versions.

```
if float(platform.python_version()[0:3]) > 3.6:
    cons = consumers.myConsumer.as_asgi()
else:
    cons = consumers.myConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/example/", cons),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/example/", cons.as_asgi()),
]
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained what this code is doing.